# How do I fix this error with the "tempmail" api

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the Temp Mail api https://temp-mail.us/en/api/ but whenever I use the given example I'm given an error. I have the api downloaded as well as everything used in it.

```
from tempmail import TempMail
email = TempMail().get_email_address()
```

The error:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZOpY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find any solutions, so I had to do it **manually**.
All I did is **opening** the tempmail website and **copy** the email and then **switch** to the next tab and **paste** the email.

This code might help

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time, requests
import clipboard

tempmail = 'https://temp-mail.org'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd()+"\\chromedriver.exe") 
delay()
#go to website
driver.get(tempmail)

time.sleep(5)

Copy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="click-to-copy"]')
Copy.click()
email = clipboard.paste()
```

Then you can **open and switch** to the next tab using:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

After that, you can **paste your email**

```
Copy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH')
Copy.click()
Copy.send_keys(email)
```

Comment: Is this happening because its a old api though? I was wondering why we cant just use the original api.

Comment: you can, but not for free I guess, check this (https://rapidapi.com/Privatix/api/temp-mail), and they explain why on their website (https://temp-mail.org/en/api/)